# What is this box next to my car's battery?

Tags: electrical, mercedes-benz, part-identification

I was looking under my car's hood when I saw this box next to and above the car battery:

[image: Box with 16 numbered holes]

The car is a 1995 Mercedes E 300 Diesel, and I noticed that there are are also 16 numbered (and 4 lettered) fuses in the fusebox. Does anyone know what this box does? My first guess (just based on location) is that it's somehow related to the electrical system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is your diagnostic connector. You will need a Mercedes-specific tool to read trouble codes stored by the computer.

[image: Trouble code connector]